# Errors in switch and case statements

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I seem to have a problem with my use of switch statements in this function, but everything looks correct to me.

```
    double pricePerUnit(int x, int y)
       double price=pricePerUnit;
       {
       switch(pricePerUnit)
       {
        case '1':
       if(estimatedQuality(x,y)<2)
       {
       price=0.5;
       break;
       }
```

This is only part of the switch statement, there are a few more cases. The errors however are only for these lines in the code.

```
    error: parameter âpriceâ is initialized
    error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition
    error: switch quantity not an integer
    error: âpriceâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    error: for each function it appears in.)
```

I am pretty new to C, so this is all kinda confusing to me. If anyone could help, that would be great. Thanks

Comment: You're missing the `{ }` around the function body.

Comment: `pricePerUnit` is a function. Why are you assigning it to a variable that should hold a number?

Comment: No, I have that after the declaration of the variable price and at the end of the switch statement, which you can't see in this

Comment: You can't put local variable declarations before the beginning of the function body. That's why it's complaining about "old-style parameter declarations".

Comment: What are you expecting `switch(pricePerUnit)` to do? `pricePerUnit` is a function name, not a value you can compare with the character `'1'`.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do, so I can't write a good answer showing how to do it correctly. What you've posted makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: What should I put there instead? Should I declare 'price' as a double, and then use that in the switch statement? I am still getting the 'switch quantity not an integer' error.

Comment: Like I said, I can't figure out what you're trying to do. What are you trying to test with the `switch`? `switch` can only be used with integer variables, not floating point variables.

Comment: I changed the variable from a floating point to an integer, and now it compiles. However, when I run it, I get "segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: If you don't explain what this is supposed to do, I can't help you.

Comment: Don't just change things randomly, you have to understand what things do.

Comment: For that specific function, it is supposed to return different values based on an input. For example, if (1,1) was inputed, it would use the result from the estimatedQuality function to determine the output in this pricePerUnit function

Comment: How does the `switch` statement relate to the inputs?

Comment: there are certain input requirements, for example if the result from the estimatedQuality function is less than 2, the pricePerUnit is automatically .5, and if it is in between 2 and 4, the pricePerUnit is automatically .75, and so on

Comment: But what is the `switch` testing? You're doing that BEFORE you call `estimatedQuality`. Is it testing `x`, `y`, or something else?

Comment: the switch is testing x and y

Comment: You can only test one of them with `switch`.

Comment: Would it make more sense to use if statments here instead of a switch statement?

Comment: I don't know, since I still don't understand what you're trying to do. What is it about `x` and `y` is it that causes you to call `estimatedQuality`?

Comment: You said it should call it when the input is `(1, 1)`. So do you want to call `estimatedQuality` if `x` and `y` are BOTH == 1?

Comment: estimatedQuality is defined elsewhere in the file, and the x and y inputs for it are the same x and y inputs for the pricePerUnit function. There are a lot of functions that test different things for a set of x,y points

Comment: and no, the input is any set of (x,y), where x and y are greater than 1 and less than 20

Comment: I don't know how to make my questions any clearer. I don't care what `estimatedQuality` does. I want to understand the logic of THIS function. It's using `switch` or `if` to decide which function it should call. So what about the inputs is it testing?

Comment: What do `x` and `y` represent in the application? Try to give your variables meaningful names, it will help people understand your code.

Comment: This is the description of what it is testing, word for word from the assignment:
In particular, the price per unit of the groveberry harvest is affected by the quality of the harvest
alone as follows:
 If the quality of the harvest is less than 2, then the price of one unit of groveberry harvest is 0:5.
 If the quality of the harvest is between 2 and 4, the price is 0:75 per unit.
 For harvest quality 4 (inclusive) to 5 (exclusive), the price is 1 per unit.
 For harvest quality 5 (inclusive) to 6 (exclusive), the price is 2 per unit.

Comment: I advise you not to use `switch`; it is not appropriate for this problem, and you do not seem to understand what it is or how it works. I suggest you *start with something small and simple, then add functionality a little at a time*. Calculate the quality of the harvest, save it in a variable, and print it out. When that's working, use an `if` to test whether it's less than 2 and print a message. When that's working, put in another `if` to print a different message if it's between 2 and 4. Proceed this way in small steps until your code is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be testing what `estimatedQuality` returns, not performing the test before calling it.

```
double pricePerUnit(int x, int y) {
    int quality = estimatedQuality(x, y);
    double price;
    if (quality < 2) {
        price = 0.5;
    } else if (quality < 4) {
        price = 0.75;
    } else if (quality == 4) {
        price = 1;
    } else if (quality == 5) {
        price = 2;
    }
    return price;
}
```

You can do it with a `switch` like this:

```
double pricePerUnit(int x, int y) {
    double price;

    switch(estimatedQuality(x, y)) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        price = 0.5;
        break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
        price = 0.75;
        break;
    case 4:
        price = 1;
        break;
    case 5:
        price = 2;
        break;
    }
    return price;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me!